# Hibernate/JPA persisting relationship changes despite cascade = REFRESH

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm running into a weird problem where an entity is being updated through a relationship that isn't set to cascade, and was hoping someone has an explanation. The basic object structure is an Article with a related Statistics object. The database table for Statistics is updated by a completely different process (outside of Hibernate, completely different JVM on a different server), but we are seeing those changes reverted to the state they were when the Article was read when we finally do a save. It would definitely make sense if it wasn't set to REFRESH, but because it is, I'm perplexed.

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private Statistics statistics;
}

@Entity
public class Statistics {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private Long views;
}
```

The weirdest thing is that it seems to be doing this regardless of the cascade type. If I put only PERSIST, or even no cascading, it still seems to be reverting the statistics numbers. I do see it doing a SELECT on the Statistics object when the Article is saved, and only performing the UPDATE statement to revert it back if it sees it has changed.

This also doesn't seem to be a problem anywhere else, we have REFRESH all over the place and it seems to behave just fine in not cascading save changes to those objects.

Here is an example of what I'm seeing...

```
Article article = articleRepository.get(1l);
// article.getStatistics().getViews() = 4
// article is detached and some amount of time goes
// underlying database table is updated and views are incremented
// article reattached with changes
articleRepository.save(article);
```

At the end of that snippet, the database shows 4 views on the statistics object, but I don't expect the save to be cascaded to the Statistics object and overwrite existing data in the database.

Comment: Defining a REFRESH cascade does not trigger anything - you will have to actually refresh the Article instance in order for the cascade to work it's magic. Can you please post the code where you expect the entities to be refreshed?

Comment: I don't expect anything to be refreshed or persisted from the Statistics object. So if the data contained in Statistics is out of date, that is fine. But I don't expect the stale data in the Statistics object to be written to the database when saving an Article—which is what is happening.

Comment: What is save doing underneath, is it just a JPA EM.merge?

Comment: I think I understand the issue now - the stale Statistics data from the application is written to the DB as if a MERGE cascade were defined. Since the merge is not cascaded, the behaviour is indeed unexpected. Locking would be a bad workaround at best and I do not have a better idea, so please excuse me for wasting your time.

Comment: Exactly! Offering help is never wasting my time, I very much appreciate your help. Thanks! Sorry for not being more clear and wasting *your* time! =)